# can i add custom params to auto reported first_open event?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics

I'm writing a flutter app that uses firebase.
when a user first open the app an automated first_open event is being reported.

is there a way to add custom parameters to the first_open event ?

I'm not sure it's even possible but I was wondering if I can disable the auto reported first_open event and to report it manually with my custom params, or to catch that first_open event from flutter and add custom params to it before it's being reported.

any ideas regarding this issue would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is no way to add custom parameters to the `first_open` event, nor to send the event from your own code.

The only solution at the moment would be to send your additional data in an additional `my_first_open` event.

If you tell a bit more about the use-case (like the type of additional data you're looking to send), we may be able to come up with a better solution.

Comment: i want to add affiliate attribution information on first_open event.  I think that creating my own custom even for that is a good solution. if you've got other ideas i'm all years. thank you for your assistance

Comment: I think that for most use cases, you could also set user properties, since they are included on all events. However, first_open is a special case since it is recorded before you would have a chance to set user properties.

Comment: So is it also not possible to add additinoal parameters to the ad_reward event? I have different places in my app where users can watch a rewarded video ad and I would like log information about which kind of reward is earned. Is that possible without creating a custom event?